# Handle WordPress JSON response with JSONKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, jsonkit

I use JSONKit to parse data from a wordpress blog.

```
NSData *wp_json = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSDictionary *posts = [wp_json objectFromJSONData]
```

the data received is JSON so when I do this it works perfectly

```
NSLog(@"%@",[posts objectForKey:@"count"]);
```

then I want to access the posts and there is the problem posts is a sub json (if I can say that) and there is X posts so I can get a big string with all the code and I don't know how to get only the id for the first post then the id for the 2nd post.

How can I do that?

The JSON response [looks like this](http://www.x-or.be/files/wp.txt) so it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your raw JSON you get back is simply a dictionary, and the posts are an array held in that dictionary.

```
NSDictionary * JSONResponse = [wp_json objectFromJSONData];
NSArray * posts = [JSONResponse objectForKey:@"posts"];
```

Each element in that array is yet another dictionary, but this time representing a post. You can iterate through it to do what you want with each post like so:

```
for(NSDictionary * post in posts) {
    //do what you want to do for each post, e.g.
    NSNumber *postId = [post objectForKey:@"id"];
}
```